# Flash messages in transient and cached pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

i have a simple contact form with an underlying transient view.

```
<f:view transient="true">

   <h:panelGroup id="messages" layout="block" > 
        <o:messages escape="false" infoClass="info" errorClass="error" globalOnly="true" rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}" />
   </h:panelGroup>  

   <h:form id="contactform">

      please enter your name:
      <h:inputText id="name" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.fieldrequired}">
      ...

   </h:form>   

</f:view>
```

this page is also cached (using omnifaces CacheControlFilter), since the content here is not really dynamic and the user only submits some request parameters. when the form has been submitted sucessfully, the managedbean adds a flash message and performs a refresh:

```
public void showSuccess() throws IOException {
    Messages.addFlashGlobalInfo("submit_success");
    Faces.refresh(); //ensure cleaning all input fields in the form
}
```

after that, the page now contains the div with the rendered faces message and this message is now present every time the user performs a GET to this page again.

```
<div id="messages">
   <ul>
     <li>Thank you for your feedback</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

is there a way to get rid of the message?

thanks in advance.